# Buffer local transient-mark-mode?

Tags: faces, transient-mark-mode

I like `transient-mark-mode` and I like that it is activated by default. But there are a few specific buffers where I'd like to deactivate it. Unfortunately, that minor mode is either on or off globally, so you can't have it in some buffers and not in some others.

It seems that a possible workaround would be to void the highlighting face on a buffer local basis. What are the involved variables? Anybody has done this?

Or is there a better workaround?

Comment: I have successfully been using `transient-mark-mode` in a buffer-local manner for the past few years, but I cannot remember all of the reasons why I made those modifications.  It may behoove you to specify an example of what it is that you are trying to achieve .... perhaps I would be able to remember more with a cup of coffee and a frame of reference ...; and/or, perhaps other forum participants may also be able to provide you with some solutions I am unaware of.

Comment: @lawlist: In a nutshell, I'd like to have transient-mark-mode activated in some buffers *and* not activated in some some other buffers, e.g., on for C & Emacs-Lisp buffers but not for Dired or shell-mode buffers.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what are the modes where you want it disabled and why.

Comment: @Stefan: Am ashamed to tell but here it is. I'm sometimes using legacy code for some dumb old in-house major-mode. And the legacy code does not properly deactive the mark after its searches and replaces, which I find visually annoying. Ironically, if I were feeling like debugging the old code, I would find transient-mark-mode a great help with spotting when and where the mark is messed up with.

Comment: @phs: There's no shame in using old code, obviously.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barely tested, but try this:

```el
(transient-mark-mode 0)

(define-minor-mode local-transient-mark-mode
  "Toggle `transient-mark-mode' (see which) for the current buffer."
  :variable transient-mark-mode)

(make-variable-buffer-local 'transient-mark-mode)

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'local-transient-mark-mode)
```

Comment: Great !!! And obvious in hindsight. I never thought that it was enough to change the status of `transient-mark-mode` and make it buffer-local.

Comment: It very much depends upon the implementation of the global mode in question, as global modes have a wide range of implementations.  In this particular case, the `transient-mark-mode` command really only exists for the purpose of setting that variable, and everything else happens elsewhere based on the variable's value; so making the variable buffer-local does appear to do the trick.